# Converting a large list with multiple elements to data frame / tibble

Tags: r

I need help!

I'm using the nhlapi package to scrape some boxscores. What I get either from the package or using `fromJSON` function is a large nested list.

I have tried everything to convert this into a data frame. I believe the issue is that when this is reshaped it introduces many NA values. I've gotten the error below several times. I'm totally stuck here.

I do not know how to replicate the problem in my own sample code, so sharing the function being used below. Thanks!

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
> check.names = TRUE,  :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 1,
> 0

```
#install.packages("nhlapi")
#library(nhlapi)

boxscores<-nhl_games_boxscore(gameIds = 2021010001:2021010002)
```

The actual API end point for one of the games:
https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/2021010001/boxscore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get an error when running your above code. It returns a large list. You can then find the list elements, which seem to be already as dataframes.
For example (I just used the first item in your range):

```
boxscores<-nhl_games_boxscore(gameIds = 2021010001)
str(boxscores[[1]]$officials)
```

Returns

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ officialType     : chr  "Referee" "Referee" "Linesman" "Linesman"
 $ official.id      : int  2303 7405 4694 7944
 $ official.fullName: chr  "Kevin Pollock" "Mitch Dunning" "Shandor Alphonso" "Caleb Apperson"
 $ official.link    : chr  "/api/v1/people/2303" "/api/v1/people/7405" "/api/v1/people/4694" "/api/v1/people/7944"
```

If you're getting error, maybe try restart?
EDIT: per comment, here is the file structure that can be viewed by clicking on boxscores in data window. You can then click through areas of interest in the main window to expand the structure. I clicked on the teams expanding arrow to get:

```
boxscores
|
+--[[1]]
  |
  +--copyright
  +--teams
    |
    +--away
      |
      +-- (other options)
      +-- players
  +--officials
```

You then just have to build a chain specifying what you want to pull from it. Let's say you want the away team. I can get this by:

```
boxscores[[1]][["teams"]][["away"]][["players"]] -> away_players
```

This then gives a list of lists. You can drill down further and create a df by:

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(1:length(away_players), function(i) {
away_players[[i]][["person"]] %>% 
  data.frame()
}) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

That goes through each list item in away_players pulls the person list, converts to df and then binds together in one df

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't realize the officials data was already a 4x4 data frame! I'm able to get that clean like you did. I was focused on the "teams" list, which drills down into numerous lists. If you could share some advice on how to shape those nested lists into a table. I feel like I must have gone down the wrong path what I was doing.

Comment: boxscores is a large complicated list. If you're using Rstudio, I recommend clicking on it in the data pane. It will then show the structure of that data in the main pane. I'll edit the answer to show the file structure with more room.

Comment: Hi. Thank you again. This is what I'm looking for. I got an error when I ran the code. I think the third parenthesis after data.frame()) needed to be after bind_rows()?   Although I cannot get this code to write a data frame it simply creates another list for me. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!.

Comment: Oops, you're right. That parentheses after data.frame() should have been after the final curly bracket (it closes lapply). I edited answer. Try again now.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you! I did not think to move the parentheses to that spot!