# Extract lists within a nested list and create dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

This is a follow up to an earlier question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77294737/extract-multiple-elements-from-a-large-list-and-put-them-in-a-dataframe-in-r).

I use the nhlapi package to scrape some boxscores, and this results in a large nested list.

```
install.packages("nhlapi")
library(nhlapi)

boxscores <- nhl_games_boxscore(gameIds = 2023020001)
```

The goal is to obtain the boxscores from multiple games, rather than just one, and combine all of the stats, along with player info, into one dataframe.

I adjusted my code as follows:

```
gameIds = c(2023020001, 2023020002) #multiple gameIds

boxscores <- nhl_games_boxscore(gameIds = gameIds)
```

Based on the previous answer, I then used:

```
away_players <- map(boxscores, \(x) boxscores[[1]][["teams"]][["away"]][["players"]])
```

Advised previously to use:

```
away_players <- map(boxscores, \(x) x[[1]][["teams"]][["away"]][["players"]])
```

But this results in a `subscript out of bounds` error which I am unsure how to resolve.

I can see that I have 2 lists of 22, which are the away teams for the two games:

```
str(away_players, list.len=2)
List of 2
 $ :List of 22
  ..$ ID8482062:List of 4
  .. ..$ person      :List of 22
```

Using the previously suggested code:

```
df_away <- away_players %>% 
  map(unlist) %>% 
  map(enframe) %>% 
  map(\(x) pivot_wider(x,
                       names_from = name,
                       values_from = value)) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Gives a `df` of 2 obs of 1060 variables.

I am sure I probably need to go down a level in the list and this could work but I am stuck on how to get there.

I would also like to add the `gameId` as a column, but I am not sure how to do this also, since the `gameId` does not appear in the initial list anywhere.

I also tried with a loop, but I must be overwriting the data as I get a df with the same 22 players twice:

```
comb_away = data.frame()
for (game_id in gameIds) {
  boxscore = nhl_games_boxscore(gameIds = gameIds)
  away_players = boxscores[[1]][["teams"]][["away"]][["players"]]
  res = away_players %>% 
    map(unlist) %>% 
    map(enframe) %>% 
    map(\(x) pivot_wider(x,
                         names_from = name,
                         values_from = value)) %>% 
    bind_rows()
  comb_away = rbind(res, comb_away)
}
```

Comment: One advantage of a for-loop as opposed to map or lapply, is that such an error can be immediately investigated by examining the loop index. I admit to puzzlement that neither of your efforts at map-ping did anything with the “x” that you used as a formal.

Answer (score 1):

```r
map(boxscores, \(x) x[[1]][["teams"]][["away"]][["players"]])
```

throws an `subscript out of bounds` error because of `[[1]]`, during the first iteration function in map it evaluates as:

```
boxscore[[1]][[1]][["teams"]][["away"]][["players"]]
```

and `boxscores[[1]][[1]]` happens to refer to a `copyright` item of the first game.

As `map()` iterates over items of input list, it passes each of those items to its function, in the context of the function the list depth is already reduced by one level, meaning that `copyright`, `teams` and `officials` are already top-level list items. With `x[[1]]` you traverse into the first of those.

I'd go with something like this:

```r
library(nhlapi)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

gameIds = c(2023020001, 2023020002) 
boxscores <- nhl_games_boxscore(gameIds = gameIds)

boxscores |>
  # assume (kmh.. ) that list from nhl_games_boxscore is in the same order as 
  # gameIds input list
  set_names(gameIds) |>
  # use map with pluck() shorthand to extract nested list element, check ?pluck
  map(list("teams", "away", "players")) |>
  # use map with a named function, `name` and `value` are passed to enframe as args 
  map(enframe, name = "id", value = "player") |>
  # bind resulting dataframes, list names to gameId column
  list_rbind(names_to = "gameId") |>
  unnest_wider(player) |>
  # we don't need to unnest the whole nested structure, 
  # hoisting a single item from person lists:
  hoist(person, "fullName")
#> # A tibble: 44 × 7
#>    gameId     id    fullName person       jerseyNumber position     stats       
#>    <chr>      <chr> <chr>    <list>       <chr>        <list>       <list>      
#>  1 2023020001 ID84… Cole Sm… <named list> 36           <named list> <named list>
#>  2 2023020001 ID84… Yakov T… <named list> 13           <named list> <named list>
#>  3 2023020001 ID84… Gustav … <named list> 14           <named list> <named list>
#>  4 2023020001 ID84… Colton … <named list> 10           <named list> <named list>
#>  5 2023020001 ID84… Tommy N… <named list> 82           <named list> <named list>
#>  6 2023020001 ID84… Filip F… <named list> 9            <named list> <named list>
#>  7 2023020001 ID84… Roman J… <named list> 59           <named list> <named list>
#>  8 2023020001 ID84… Luke Sc… <named list> 2            <named list> <named list>
#>  9 2023020001 ID84… Samuel … <named list> 11           <named list> <NULL>      
#> 10 2023020001 ID84… Alexand… <named list> 45           <named list> <named list>
#> # ℹ 34 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: this is great! How would we unnest all of the lists? I need to see all person / position / stats details. Also would you repeat this for home team players and perhaps rbind as I need those also?

Comment: 1- you most likely need to go through a series of unnest() / unnest_wider() / unnest_longer() operations to shape that frame for your need and so that it makes sense (you'll know for sure when you have untested in the wrong direction) . Process is sometimes called rectangling and there's this nice Vignette - https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rectangle.html .   2 - you can replace `away` with `home` in the first `map()` call .